# Using MySQL's COUNT with two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL table called tbl_pet_owners:

```
+--------+----------+--------+
| name   | pet      | city   |
+========+==========+========+
| jane   | cat      | Boston |
+--------+----------+--------+
| jane   | dog      | Boston |
+--------+----------+--------+
| jack   | cat      | Boston |
+--------+----------+--------+
| jim    | snake    | Boston |
+--------+----------+--------+
| jim    | goldfish | Boston |
+--------+----------+--------+
| joseph | cat      | NYC    |
+--------+----------+--------+
```

I want to use COUNT to get the number of pets per city, BUT if an individual owns two or more pets of the same type, then those pets are counted as one. The pet types are listed in another MySQL table called tbl_pet_types:

```
+----------+---------+
| pet      | type    |
+==========+=========+
| cat      | mammal  |
+----------+---------+
| dog      | mammal  |
+----------+---------+
| snake    | reptile |
+----------+---------+
| goldfish | fish    |
+----------+---------+
```

So since jane's cat and dog are of the same type, they're considered one pet.
In this example, the result would be:

```
Boston 4
NYC    1
```

Any tips on how to achieve this?

Comment: So you are grouping by City, Owner and PetType?

Comment: yes. that's correct.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Look to `Join` the `tbl_pet_types` table.

Comment: SELECT city, COUNT(DISTINCT name, pet) FROM tbl_pet_owners GROUP BY city

Comment: What do you get when you try that?

Comment: Boston 5, NYC 1

Comment: Because both jane's cat and dog are counted. But since the dog and cat are of the same type-and they're both owned by jane-, I want them to be counted as one.

Comment: Join the `tbl_pet_types` and in the `Count()` replace `pet` with `type`

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet? I don't know how join works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be optimized, but works:

```
select count(*), result.city from (
    select owners.city, types.type, owners.name
    from tbl_pet_owners owners
    left join tbl_pet_types types on owners.pet = types.pet group by owners.city, owners.name, types.type
) as result
group by result.city;
```

Answer (score 2):

See if this works.

```
SELECT PO.city, COUNT(DISTINCT PO.name, PT.type) 
FROM tbl_pet_owners PO
JOIN tbl_pet_types PT ON PO.pet = PT.pet 
GROUP BY PO.city
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.city, COUNT(DISTINCT o.name, t.type)
FROM tbl_pet_owners o, tbl_pet_types t
WHERE o.pet = t.pet
GROUP BY city
```